# Remove WWW from the URL in Docker for php-application

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a dockerized locally a PHP application.i have all the files in the WWW folder. 
when I hit localhost:8200 it shows access denied.
but when I hit localhost:8200/www it brings up the index page.

can anyone please tell me how to remove www.

This is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3"
services:
    www:
        build: .
        ports: 
            - "8200:80"
        volumes:
            - ./www:/var/www/html/
        networks:
            - default
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM php:5.6-apache 
ADD www.tar.gz .
```

Comment: Are you trying in the docker compose to overwrite the `www.tar.gz` you added inside the image?

Comment: Your www.tar.gz file probably has a folder named www, so that folder is created and you end up with /var/www/html/www/your_files. Try to extract the targz and add the files right at the root of the tarball.

Comment: @Mihai  actually when I try to access with docker image this issue happens

Comment: What do you mean "access with docker image"?

Comment: @ Marc Sances ya exactly I have the same problem can you please help me in extracting the targz and add the files right at the root

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 "conflicting" statements: the volumes declaration in your docker-compose.yml and the ADD command in the Dockerfile.

The ADD is the one that actually works for you so you should remove the volume declaration.

ADD with archive will unpack the archive as a directory so you would better use:

```
ADD ./www/ .
```

This way only the contents of ./www will be copied, not the directory itself.

Comment: When i am using image this is my compose file                                                version: "3"
services:
    www:
        image: westlawchina-mkt_www
        ports: 
            - "8200:80"
        networks:
            - default

Comment: Can you just try these changes?

Comment: That is because you are using the old image. You need to rebuild the image with the changes I mentioned (the new Dockerfile).

Comment: I built the new image but also having the same problem

Comment: I did test this and it worked so I have the feeling you are missing a step. Can you update the post with exactly all the commands you run and the exact version of the docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile that you are using?

Comment: This is my docker compose file when I am using the image       version: "3"
services:
    www:
        image: westlawchina-mkt_www
        ports: 
            - "8200:80"
        networks:
            - default

Comment: and this is my docker file    FROM php:5.6-apache 
ADD ./www.tar.gz .

Comment: Don't use the image

Comment: actuall i have to create a docker i image to deploy on server

Comment: This is my script file rm www.tar.gz
tar -cvf www.tar ./www
gzip -f www.tar

docker-compose up --build   is anything wrong in this

Comment: Yes. You should not tar

Comment: if I will tar then how I will bring the site file to the docker image

Comment: @Mahia actually it tar's all the files in the WWW folder and the folder also. I want to tar only the files inside the WWW folder.

Comment: `tar -cvf www.tar ./www/*` but this will not solve your issue